# rerendering drop down doesn.t work properly lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have 2 embedded components on the layout of Account.
One component its custom upload attachment component
another-responsible for displaying attachemnts in drop down list  and displaying selected attachemnt within iframe

I have the following `inputselect`

**AttachmentViewer.cmp**

```
<aura:component access="global" controller="AttachmentViewerControl" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
....
      <aura:attribute name="attachments" type="AttachmentViewerControl.AttachmentWrapper[]" default=""></aura:attribute>

        <ui:inputSelect aura:id="allAttachs" label="All attachments" change="{!c.onSelectChange}">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.attachments}" var="attach">
                                <ui:inputSelectOption class="{!attach.cssClass}"  text="{!attach.id}" label="{!attach.name}"/>
                            </aura:iteration>
        </ui:inputSelect>
```

when file have been uploaded `rerenderDropDown` event fires 
which is been  handled in `AttachmentViewer" component which include dropdown

**AttachmentViewer.cmp**

```
<aura:handler name="updateDropDown" event="c:rerenderDropDown"
                  action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

**controLler:**

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper){
        helper.getAllWrapperAttachments(component,event,helper);
    },
```

....

**helper:**

```
 getAllWrapperAttachments: function(component, event, helper) {
var self=this;
 var action = component.get("c.getAllwrapperAttachments");
        action.setParams({
            parentId: component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(resp) {
            var state = resp.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                var attachs = resp.getReturnValue();
                console.log('fromControllerAttachs>>>>',attachs);

                component.set("v.attachments",attachs);
                var testAttachs = component.get("v.attachments");

                console.log('testAttahxs>>>>>',testAttachs);

            }   else if (state == 'ERROR') {
                var errors = resp.getError();
                if (errors[0].message) {
                    console.log('>>>>>>'+errors[0].message);
                }
            }

        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

And everything works fine except the one use case.

so you can seecorrect behavior  when:

login in salesforce-click account tab-click particular record- **reload page** try upload attachment.

incorrect behavior when:
  from record layout- click account tab- click this record again. In this case when I'm trying to upload attachment - all logs are filing up with proper values : `console.log('fromControllerAttachs>>>>',attachs);`
so event fired ok;
id passed to controoler ok;
callback response - ok;

but nothing re-renders!!
if you try refresh page again -then you can see changes in dropdown.

Try to upload attachment and dropdown rerenders properly.

But if you try to repeat steps from *incorrect behavior* -again dropdown are not re-rendered!

Its looks like a bug I think